# LibGDX rotate texture once and use the rotated one

Tags: rotation, textures, libgdx

I know you can draw a rotated texture by using some cool rotation stuff in `SpriteBatch` class but everywhere i can only find how to *draw* a rotated texture, not how to *rotate* a texture or *create* a rotated texture.

I need to rotate the texture once (since it is saved rotated by 90°) and then use it for the rest of the time, as far as i'm concerned, i would replace the pixels one-by-one to achive the rotation, I just really dont want to rotate it 100000 times if i really need to rotate it only once.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Texture texture =new Texture("path"); //or how you get your texture
Sprite s=new Sprite(texture);
s.setRotation(90);
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: in that case make sure to dispose the pixmap when its use is over as it causes lots of memory leaks and bad performance in mobile devices